# PHP MYSQL выдает ошибку и страница не грузится

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, mysqli

Код:

```
$mysql = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'test', '8889');
$result = $mysql->query("SELECT * FROM `users`");
print_r($result);
echo $result;
$mysql->close();
```

Если что все параметры в запросе совпадают с теми, которые записаны через PHPMYAdmin.

Comment: нет, не совпадают. во второй строке кода это даже видно

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701142/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-php-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5)

Comment: Если воспользоваться советами в дубликате - вы тоже сможете видеть сообщения об ошибках

Comment: Как вы определили то не совпадают? Это могу проверить только я через phpmyadmin

Comment: если в админке работает - а тут нет - уже показатель что не совпадают.........к тому же, я  вижу конкретно в чём потенциальная проблема.... поэтмоу вам советую посмотреть вопрос дубликат, включить отображение ошибок и посмотреть что скажет вам........ + попробуйте вот прямо сейчвас скопировать свой запрос из кода и вставить в phpmyadmin - он уже не сработает

Comment: В админке скопировал запрос и он работает

Comment: вы говорите неправду

Comment: https://ibb.co/nskH0YX

Comment: запрос отличается от того, что приведён в вопросе здесь. А после того как вы поправили, начал совпадать. Теперь нужно посмотреть в логи сервера и найти там ошибку, если она есть

Comment: а вот теперь проверьте свой исправленный код на исполнение

Comment: Не работает. Теперь страница просто выдает код 500

Comment: Смотрите ошибку в логах. Вангую, что из-за `print_r` потому что `$result` - это не массив

Comment: 500 это ошибка на сервере и я уже третий раз вам повторяю: откройте вопрос дубликат и почитайте все ответы внимательно..там всё написано, как стоит ловить ошибки

Answer (score 0):

Нужно было $result достать. А я его просто как запрос пытался вывести. Вот верный ответ:

```
$user = $result->fetch_assoc();
```